# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On my client side, I simply want to aler the response I get from the server.

```
function displayItems()
{
    fetch('http://ip_address:3000/users',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        mode:'no-cors'
    })
    .then((response) => {return response.json();})
    .then((res) => { alert(res.message)})
}
```

On my server side, I have this simple code to respond to request

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  let obj = {message:'fsdfsdfsdfsd'}
  res.send(obj);

  console.log('server Reached')
});

module.exports = router;
```

After looking up other related problems, I am still unable to resolve this error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

Thank you in advance to those who look at this.

Answer (score 3):

**In addition** to the `no-cors` problem Quentin pointed out with the duplicate (which he answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47456842/157247)), there are several other issues:

What you're sending isn't JSON:

```
res.send('Hello world'); // <=== This is plain text
```

...so `response.json()` would fail when trying to parse the response.

If you're just sending text like that, you'd use `response.text()` to read it instead of `.json()`.

You're also not checking correctly for HTTP errors. It's not just you, almost everyone makes this mistake (which I've [written up here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)), it's a flaw (IMHO) in the `fetch` API. To correctly check for errors and receive text (rather than JSON), see `***` comments:

```
function displayItems()
{
    fetch('http://172.30.117.7:3000/users',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        mode:'no-cors'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        // *** Check for HTTP failure
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
        }
        // *** Read the text of the response
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((message) => {
        // *** Use the text
        alert(message);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        /* ...*** handle/report error, since this code doesn't return the promise chain...*/
    });
}
```

---

Alternately, if you wanted, you could send back JSON:

```
response.json({message: "Hi there"});
```

...and then on the client:

```
function displayItems()
{
    fetch('http://172.30.117.7:3000/users',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        mode:'no-cors'
    })
    .then((response) => {
        // *** Check for HTTP failure
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
        }
        // *** Read and parse the JSON
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        // *** Use the object
        alert(res.message);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        /* ...*** handle/report error, since this code doesn't return the promise chain...*/
    });
}
```

**But again**, all of that is aside from the primary problem Quentin pointed out with the duplicate.

Comment: If `Hello World` was the issue, it would complain that `H` was invalid JSON. It's failing with unexpected end of content because of the no-cors mode.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks, I guess the error would be different, wouldn't it? All of the above still applies, so I've marked it CW and called out that these are *separate*, additional issues. Thanks again!

Comment: That was stupid of me. I modified my code. Essentially I and trying to print the key value pair of the object.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry for the first code, I initially wanted to send an object as a message. I added the checks and the I changed 'no-cors' to 'cors'. I get this error now 'from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.' How can I make the server allow for reading the response using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Comment: @Quentin The Following code was added:app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  next();
}); and I still get the CORS policy error. Please help me

Comment: @PatrickAdjei - You should be able to find solutions for CORS in Express using [this search](/search?q=%5Bexpress%5D+cors).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understood and found the solution to my problem. Thank you